# Change DHCP server from ISP modem to network router

Tags: dns, dhcp, nat, gateway

I have an ISP provided DSL modem/router (Archer) that is currently configured as 192.168.1.1 and acts as the gateway, DHCP server, and the DNS settings are also stored there. I also have my own ASUS DSL modem/router currently configured as 192.168.1.2 (and some additional routers that allow for ASUS' AiMesh networking) that I'd ideally connect straight to my ISP, but I can't get it to connect, so I'm going to disable wifi on the Archer and manage all of my Wifi from the ASUS router.

But that would leave me with a DHCP server configured on the Archer modem and on the ASUS router. Can I just disable the DHCP server on the Archer and enable it on the ASUS, and reboot?

With DHCP server disabled on the Archer modem, should I still consider the Archer the default gateway, and leave gateway/DNS/NAT settings as they are (i.e. only change the DHCP server setting) or should I now treat the ASUS router as the gateway, having updated the DHCP server settings only, or do I also need to configure the ASUS router to handle all gateway tasks?

In short, can the Archer remain the gateway, and it's just changing the DHCP server settings, or do I need to do more)?

Comment: This is a more complex question than it appears... Your "default gateway" would still be the Archer router, because that is the "gateway" to get outside of your local subnet. If the Asus router can set the gateway address that it hands out in DHCP as the Archer router, then this should be a simple thing. Unfortunately, many consumer routers, especially DSL/Router AIO devices, cannot set a different gateway then themselves, meaning you would need a 3rd party DHCP server. But my question is why bother? It doesn't matter which device hands out DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get into the ISP Archer modem/router, you should be able to configure it to only act as the gateway.

But I'm also wondering since you note having your own DSL modem/router if you've considered having that be the gateway as well?  Most ISPs will let you use your own.  They usually have a list of supported/allowed -- I suspect for them to push fw as well as test to verify.  The times I've done it, it's been a fairly easy call to give them the MAC of my modem & sometimes they ask for the MAC of their's.  I initially did this to avoid having to pay a modem rental fee when high speed internet was finally available in my area back in the day.

Comment: ISP's have a list of "approved" modems so that they know they will be compatible with their service, they do not push their own firmware into a customer owned device. Typically with DSL they would have to provision the modem on the ISP end, and it would have PPPoE or similar credentials that would need to be setup in the CPE router, depending on the DSL implementation. Unlike DOCSIS cable modems, DSL is not just "register the device's MAC address" with the ISP and it works, there is generally more settings that need to go into the router/modem itself that you need to get from your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

Turn off DHCP on ASUS and connect one of the LAN ports of the ASUS router to the Archer's LAN port through the network cable. The goal is to use your ASUS router as a switch.